# Need help with the convolution of two complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

Could someone start me off with how to find the convolution of these two functions?

[image: convolution]

Using the normal equation for convolution seems impossible as a common overlap interval is required for integration. The Fourier convolution theorems also seems inapplicable here.

Comment: $$(f_1\ast f_2)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_1(x-y)f_2(y)\,dy$$ is well-defined for these two functions. They both belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm still a first year undergrad student, so the whole L^2 functions are new to me. Could you explain the process a little further for me?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you knew a little bit of that since you spoke of the Fourier convolution theorems, at least one of which has its natural home in $L^2$. Anyway, for any fixed $x$, the function $h_x(y) = f_1(x-y)f_2(y)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and integrable. Thus the function $x\mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} h_x(y)\,dy$ is well-defined (and continuous, but that needs some argument to prove).

Comment: Oh I meant the theorems that go with the Fourier Transform and stuff. These: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html
This question is from an assignment from my course. It's way over what we actually learned in class. I've been piecing together my assignment by asking a lot of questions on this place. I'm supposed to find the convolution of these and actually obtain a result. The variable of integration ('y' in your equation) of the convolution equation is the overlap of the two functions, right? If they both have infinite limits, what would that variable be for this instance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "overlap". Both functions are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (and square-integrable), so the convolution is given by the formula above. Computing it may be quite hard (depends on what you can use; if you know the residue theorem, it's easy, but I don't think first year undergraduates have that yet).

Comment: Overlap as in the common limits of both the functions. Yeah, I haven't even heard of that yet :(. The only way I could think of was by using equation (8) here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html) and finding the inverse transform of the result. But it seems very long and complicated. I thought there would be a simpler way.